# Is $(\omega:_{Q(R)}\omega)=R$ for a canonical ideal $\omega$ of a one-dimensional local Cohen-Macaulay ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local ring of dimension $1$ admitting a canonical ideal $\omega\subseteq R$. Then $\omega$ contains a non-zero divisor. Let $Q(R)$ be the total ring of fractions of $R$. Since $\omega$ contains a non-zero divisor, we have an Isomorphism $(\omega:_{Q(R)}\omega)\cong \text{Hom}_R(\omega, \omega)\cong R$. Hence we have $(\omega:_{Q(R)}\omega)=qR$ for some $q\in Q(R)$.

My question is: Is it actually true that $(\omega:_{Q(R)}\omega)=R$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is true. A fractional ideal $\omega$ of a Cohen-Macaulay ring $R$ (not necessarily local) is a canonical module if and only if it contains a regular element and $(\omega:(\omega:I))=I$ for every fractional ideal $I$ containing a regular element. When $I=R$ you get your equality. What is your definition of canonical module?

Comment: @Francesco: my definition of Canonical module is as can be found in the book of Bruns&Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay rings. (Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualizing_module#:~:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20a%20dualizing,used%20in%20Grothendieck%20local%20duality.). I guess the reason actual equality $R=(\omega: \omega)$ holds is because not only do we know that Hom$_R(\omega, \omega)\cong R$, but we do also know that the homothety $R\to Hom(\omega, \omega)$ is an Isomorphism ...